# Ruby Update Attribute with Sum of Database Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, attributes, sum

I have a database with three values: `tips_value`, `profile_value`, and `value`. For each entry in the database, whenever I update the entry, I want to take the sum of `tips_value` and `profile_value` and assign it to `value`, but it's not working.

Here is my update function:

```
def update
    @affinity = Affinity.find(params[:id])

    if @affinity.update_attributes(params[:affinity])
        update_column(@affinity.value, @affinity.tips_value + @affinity.profile_value)
        redirect_to @affinity
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to make `before_update`, that would take care of updating your `value` in DB, whenever you change `tips_value` or `profile_value`, and from anywhere.

In your Affinity model add

```
before_update :sync_value_amount

private

def sync_value_amount
   self.value = self.tips_value + self.profile_value
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make before_update call back in your model

Like:

```
before_update  :set_value

private
  def set_value
     self.value= @affinity.tips_value + @affinity.profile_value
  end
```